# ListView with CheckedTextView doesn't stay checked (mode SINGLE)

Tags: android, listview

WHAT I HAVE:
I'm using CheckedTextView with ListView. A row in ListView is a CheckedTextView (same id all time). ListView has set choice mode to CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE.

PROBLEM:
OnItemCliked nothing happen. "CheckBox" (rounded) stay unchecked. ...I tried to implement onItmeClickedListener like that

`CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView)view;

ctv.setChecked(!ctv.isChecked());`

Comment: first check if enter the code where you have written ctv.setChecked(!ctv.isChecked());  try debug your code or print toast

Comment: i have already add toast which show id of row but when i uncommenct the code setChecked i get error ClassCastException:android.widget.linerlayout
i use listview and than SimpleCursorAdapter where attribut to is id of CheckedTextView 
TextCheckedView in xml looks like:
`
<LinearLayout>  
  <CheckedTextView>  
  </CheckedTextView>  
</LinearLayout>
`